# ASP.NET create dynamic table contains rowspan property

Tags: asp.net

> I want to create a dynamic table. Below you can see between starsign
>   has to be dynamic. Plant name (dynamic)=DAP1,TUP1,GEP3,PSP2
>   Config name (dynamic)= KSROC, 100ROC          Key figure name
>   (dynamic) = Max Capacity, Free Capacity, Loading Level and of course i
>   want to have it with rowspan mentioned below code. Thanks for the help
>   i am just stuck

```
<table class="table1">
         <thead>
             <tr>
                     <th>Config</th>
                     <th>Key Figure</th>
                     <th>*DAP1*</th>
                     <th>*TUP1*</th>
                     <th>*GEP3*</th>
                     <th>*PSP2*</th>
             </tr>
         </thead>        
             <tr>                     
                     <th rowspan="4">*KSROC*</th>                    
                     <tr>
                        <th>*Max Capacity*</th>
                        <td>*will be populated according to DAP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to TUP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to GEP3*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to PSP2*</td>                   
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>*Free Capacity*</th>
                        <td>*will be populated according to DAP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to TUP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to GEP3*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to PSP2*</td>  
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>*Loading Level*</th>
                        <td>*will be populated according to DAP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to TUP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to GEP3*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to PSP2*</td>  
                     </tr>
             </tr>             

                     <th rowspan="4" >*100ROC*</th>
                     <tr>
                        <th>*Max Capacity*</th>
                        <td>*will be populated according to DAP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to TUP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to GEP3*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to PSP2*</td>                   
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>*Free Capacity*</th>
                        <td>*will be populated according to DAP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to TUP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to GEP3*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to PSP2*</td>  
                     </tr>
                     <tr>
                        <th>*Loading Level*</th>
                        <td>*will be populated according to DAP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to TUP1*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to GEP3*</td>
                        <td>*will be populated according to PSP2*</td>  
                     </tr>
             </tr>

     </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use asp.net `Repeater`, in this [tutorial](http://www.netrostar.com/Tutorials-91-ASP.NET%20Tutorial.%20How%20to%20use%20Repeater) there is an example of how to use it.

Comment: This answer is completely wrong.The link contains data binding to the repeater.It doesnt make any sense or help me tp create a dynamic table with rowspan property.Can you please help with my example